# Zend DB Join Multiple Tables with Multi Count

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, magento, join

I am trying to join two tables to my maintable as follows:

bannermanager_banner = main_table

bannermanager_banner_click = table I want a record count where maintable.id = banner_click_table.banner_id

bannermanager_banner_impression = table I want a record count where maintable.id = banner_impression_table.banner_id

I have tried many things, the closed I have got is this:

```
    $this->getSelect()
        ->join(array('bc' => $this->getTable('vortex_bannermanager/banner_click')), 'bc.banner_id=main_table.id', array('banner_click_count' => 'count(bc.id)'))
        ->join(array('bi' => $this->getTable('vortex_bannermanager/banner_impression')), 'bi.banner_id=main_table.id', array('banner_impression_count' => 'count(bi.id)'))
        ->group('main_table.id');
```

But the counts are returning the total of both each =S

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By nature of count and group by you can't really achieve it this way. If you need multiple counts in one query you need to use subquery's.

Comment: Cheers, that exactly what I did =]